# Video Processing to detect certain actions from a video

Tags: matlab, video, image-processing, neural-network, video-processing

My current project is to gather data from a sports video using video processing techniques. Specifically, in sports like Tennis or badminton, I want to identify the type of shots taken.
So, I thought of two methods to do this:

1. Use motion detection techniques and highlight only the players and the ball in the foreground, then use some kind of a filtering algorithm like the Kalman filter to track the player and then track the motion of their hands separately. This method seems to be really hard and complicated, I cannot seem to track the players accurately at all.
2. Supplying a collection of videos of a particular shot to a neural network, make it train and identify those shots eventually. But I do not know how to supply videos as inputs to a neural networks and I'm not clear as to which software is ideal for this application.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score -1):

The second option looks better to me. Maybe have a look at how images are fed to neural networks, for example in [Alexnet](http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4824-imagenet-classification-with-deep-convolutional-neural-networks.pdf). Then feeding videos should not be too different. You'll probably have to first decode the videos, though.